# Opencart - Product count next to each manufacturer for allowed products only

Tags: count, opencart, product

I am showing count of products next to each manufacturer. But the number is misleading because of it count all products, I mean allowed and disallowed product too. How to count and display **only allowed products count** next to manufacturer?

I am using OC 2.3.0.2.
vQmod Show Count Products of Manufacturers contain:

```
`(".$manufacturer['products_count'].")";`
```

On the brand page is for brand Montura counted 12 pieces.

[brand montura 12 pcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUPAw.png)

but in brand product list are showing just 11 pieces
[brand montura 11 pcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQlvO.png)

Comment: Provide some code for batter understanding.

Comment: What have you tried so far? give us some code

Comment: I didn't tried anything at this moment & provide some details